# Is it possible to programmatically authenticate with Spring Security and make it persistent?

Tags: java, security, spring, spring-security

I'm using the following method in a Spring Controller to allow authentication via Ajax. It works, but it doesn't seem to create a cookie or anything that makes the authentication persistent.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public LoginStatus login(@RequestParam("j_username") String username,
                         @RequestParam("j_password") String password) {

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);

    try {
        Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        return new LoginStatus(auth.isAuthenticated(), auth.getName());
    } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
        return new LoginStatus(false, null);
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to make the authentication persistent?

Comment: Matt - did you ever figure this one out? I'm trying to do the exact same thing now. Going to try this code from the Spring Security forums: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?99183-Automatic-login-after-account-creation

Comment: Yes, see the following comment and post for the solution: http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/implementing_ajax_authentication_using_jquery#comment-1300943308000

Answer (score 3):

Make sure

- you have `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` configured
- you are not setting `create-session` attribute of `<security:http>` tag to `none`.

Comment: I tried looking at the logic in SecurityContextPersistenceFilter and replicating it. I added a reference to SecurityContextRepository and tried calling its saveContext() method after authenticating the user. Still no dice.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to you to configure Spring Security filter chain in a standard manner rather than mimicing it? Btw, note the `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` javadoc: _This filter MUST be executed BEFORE any authentication processing mechanisms. Authentication processing mechanisms (e.g. BASIC, CAS processing filters etc) expect the SecurityContextHolder to contain a valid SecurityContext by the time they execute_. This means the context creating and storage should occur _prior_ to performing authentication.

Comment: I've successfully used this technique to talk to j_security_check and get it working as good as the LoginService implementation. However, I'm still facing the same issues with getting the HTTPS login to persist to HTTP. I've created a j_security_check branch in the GitHub project to try and get this alternative implementation working. https://github.com/mraible/ajax-login/tree/j_security_check